# Show a PopOver when fullscreen video

Tags: swift, popup, webkit, popover

I have an App that plays videos using webkit (it's a event streaming app) and I want to make sure if the user is paying attention, my idea is to show a popover asking if the user is there with a simple yes button.

What is the best way to make iOS show this button during a fullscreen mode?